# fgets stops before reading to the end of csv, and wrong output

Tags: c, csv, fgets

I use fgets to read csv, which has 100000 lines.

```
int** readCsv(char *str) {

    char file_name[100];
    strcpy (file_name, PATH);
    strcat( file_name, str);
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r");

    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        //return 1;
    }

    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    int *result = NULL;
    int **arr;
    int len[ROW];
    arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * ROW);
    int row = 0;

    while(fgets(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp) != NULL) {
        int column;
        printf("%s\n", line);
        // plus one because the last number did not be added with comma
        column = countComma(line) + 1;
        len[row] = column;
        printf("%d\t", column);
        result = strtok(line, ",");
        arr[row] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
        column = 0;
        while( result != NULL ) {
            arr[row][column] = atoi(result);
            //printf("%d\t", arr[row][column]);
            result = strtok(NULL, ",");
            column++;
        }
        printf("%d\n", row);
        //printf("\n");
        row++;
    }
    fclose (fp);
    return arr;
}
```

and it stopped at line 5256, out of 100000. The data that it read was also wrong (the data of line 5256 is originally data of line 5276). I don't know where went wrong, any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks guys!

[where it stoppted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mj7hM.jpg)
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMUfY.jpg)

(I set MAX_LINE_SIZE to 100000. if this information helps)

Comment: One possibility is a stack issue.  Having a local array of size 100000 seems a little high.  If you change MAX_LINE_SIZE to 10000 do you stop in the same spot?

Comment: Also, check the results on you malloc call to make sure it didn't fail.

Comment: @jmq from the screen shot of the file perhaps `1000` will be enough for each line but if `100000` was going to break the stack, it wouldn't wait until halfway through the file.

Comment: @WeatherVane I never thought it was the number of lines.  However, I have worked on systems where 100000 bytes on the stack would cause problems.  I don't know the details on the author's development environment so I wanted to rule that out just in case.

Comment: @jmq yes, there is `int len[100000]` too which takes up even more stack.

Comment: Most likely cause seems to be not checking `malloc`. It would be easy to check that. And BTW `int len[ROW]` isn't even being used, nor will it be accessible by the caller. `arr` should really be a `struct` type which contains the number of elements and the pointer.

Comment: Aside: `int *result = NULL;` should be `char *result = NULL;` and the compiler should warn about that. Are you ignoring any other warnings?

Comment: When asking a question about a run time problem, as this question is doing, always post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it

Comment: OT: regarding this kind of statement: `arr[row] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * column);`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL)  the returned value to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: regarding: `result = strtok(NULL, ",");`  this is not allowing for spaces nor newlines.  suggest:  `result = strtok(NULL, ", ");` and after calling `fgets()` always trim the newline via: `line[ strcsp( line, "\n" ) ] = '\0';`

Comment: the posted code fails to compile!  it is missing lots of items, like the macro definitions. the `#include` statements, etc.  please correct, then post a [mcve]

Comment: regarding: `fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n")`  This is not necessarily correct.  Suggest: `perror( "failed to open file for reading");` as that will output both your error message and the text reason the system thinks the error occurred to `stderr`

Comment: regarding: `if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n");
        //return 1;
    }`  Best to not comment out the statement: `return 1;` because if the open failed, then should not be trying to read from the file.

Comment: @heisthere, what is the definition for ROW.  It not listed here.  If it less than 100000, that probably your error.  Baring you have no issues in the countComma routine, your code should run even with the issues everybody is pointing out.  I made some minor adjustment and assumptions to your code and was able to get it to run without error.   Note not having your data, my data consist of the first line copied 100000 times.  Also, I introduce some minor data issues (padded spaces and invalid numeric data) still no access violation error.  (Use OpenVMS, but Windows should work as well)

Comment: @ Weahther Vane @ jmq @Mentat Thanks a lot! It's exactually the reason! I forgot to set the row while i changed to test this larger file. It should be 100000 rather than 1000!!!

Comment: @Weather Vane I do got the warning about the  ```int *result = Null

``` I will try it though, 1000 time thanks!

Comment: @user3629249 Wow, Thanks for the suggestions!! I am quite new at C, thanks for that, I will try the tips and revise them ^^

Comment: @user3629249 Altough if (!fp) { fprintf(stderr, "failed to open file for reading\n"); //return 1; since the function returns a int ** , i couldn't just return single 1, should I cast it to (int **)1 to return?

Comment: when an unrecoverable error occurs, it is (usually) best to cleanup (close files, free allocated memory, etc) then call `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`   Note: both `exit()` and `EXIT_FAILURE` are from the header file: `stdlib.h`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had type this up earlier but delay posting it since I could not find anything in your code to cause an access violation.  But now that you identified the issue.  I thought I sum up what I and other found wrong with your code.  Note most of my observations are mostly style preference and not that you really did anything wrong.

Hera is a breakdown of the problems I see in your code.

**File error handling**

Since your routine is expected to return a pointer address, you should return a NULL value whenever an error is encountered.  This signals to the caller, who should be checking for nulls, that something went wrong.  Also, consider using the [perror()](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/perror) function.  Along with displaying a message you provide, it will also add a reason text for the IO error.

```
if (fp)
{
   perror("failed to open file for reading.");
   return NULL;
}
```

Sample output on open error:

```
failed to open file for reading: file not found.
```

**The MAX_LINE_SIZE and ROW values**

The variable use to read each line only needs to be the size of the longest line in the file plus 2 bytes that represent the line terminator and null character (see [fgets documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/stdio.h/fgets)).  It should not be set to the max lines contains in the file.  You can over size it, but 100000 is way too big.  Not knowing your data, you should consider something smaller like 1024.  ROW should be set to the max lines expected to be read in.

```
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE 1024
#define ROW 100000
```

**Allocation error handling**

Always check to see if an allocation routine was successfully.  Again, since the caller should be checking for nulls, if any errors are encountered, abort with a null return value.

```
arr = (int **)malloc(sizeof(int *) * ROW);
if ( arr == NULL ) return NULL;
```

and here

```
arr[row] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
if ( arr[row] == NULL ) return NULL;
```

**Trim extra character added by fgets()**

There are many ways to accomplish this but you should remove the line terminator from your data.  Below is one suggestion in doing this:

```
if ( strlen(line) > 0 ) line[strlen(line)-1] = 0;
```

**Grouping statements**

Try to group statements that perform a certain task together.  This will make your code easier to read.

Example 1: Column allocation logic

```
column =  countComma(line) +1;
arr[row] = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * column);
len[row] = column;
```

Example 2:  String parse logic

```
column = 0;
result = strtok(line, ",");
while ( result != NULL ) {
    arr[row][column] = atoi(result);
    //printf("%d\t", arr[row][column]);
    result = strtok(NULL, ",");
    column++;
}
```

**strtok return type**

You should have received a warning for this, but “result” should be defined as a char pointer and not an int pointer.  (see [strtok documentation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_strtok.htm))

```
char *result = NULL;
```

As mention by my comment below, my version of your code ran fine without most of these suggestions.  The suggestions here are just my observations and opinions.  Use your own judgment when considering any of these suggestions.

Comment: Thanks a loooot!! I revised my code following your suggestions, they really made it much easier to read!